# Sublime Text 3 SCSS-Contrib-Lint not using .scss-lint.yml

Tags: sass, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I can't seem to get SublimeLinter-scss-contrib-lint to work in Sublime Text 3.  I have the .scss-lint.yml file in my root, and it appears to run off the command line (though whether off my file or default settings I'm not sure).  I've installed the package via Package Manager and it is in my SublimeLinter.sublime.settings file, but when I make errors on purpose they are never picked up.

```
// Snippet of .scss-lint.yml
scss_files: "/app/www/scss/*.scss"

linters:
  BangFormat:
    enabled: true
    space_before_bang: true
    space_after_bang: false

  BorderZero:
    enabled: true

  ColorKeyword:
    enabled: true

  Comment:
    enabled: true

// Sublime Linters
"linters": {
    "annotations": {
        ... // removed linter settings for readability, but to show which ones I'm using
    },
    "csslint": {
        ...
    },
    "jshint": {
        ...
    },
    "json": {
        ...
    },
    "php": {
        ...
    },
    "scss": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "exclude-linter": "",
        "excludes": [],
        "include-linter": ""
    }
},
```

There are a bunch of different stackoverflow questions on this, but none seem to fit my question.  I'm using Windows if that helps, and all the gems are installed and working.

Comment: I just installed the gem and the sublime plugin and it worked out of the box after I upgraded to the newest SublimeLint (even without creating a `.scss-lint.yml`). You could set the SublimeLinter debug mode to true and view the Sublime console to see if errors are shown up.

Answer (score 2):

It seems submlimelinter-scss-lint caches configs at runtime. Restarting sublime did the trick for me.

https://github.com/attenzione/SublimeLinter-scss-lint/issues/19

My .scss-lint.yml that lives at project root:

```
scss_files: 'src/css/**/*.scss'

linters:
  Indentation:
    severity: warning
    width: 1
    character: tab
```

Comment: It's worth noting that your `.scss-lint.yml` config file can be placed either at the root of your current project for local use, or in your **Home Directory** for global use. On a mac your Home Directory is located at `~`. On Windows, your Home Directory [depends on the operating system you're running](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system).